# Generating QR code in iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, qr-code

In my app I am looking to generate a QR code. Now I have already looked at a couple of classes online but none of them seem to work, including this one https://github.com/myang-git/QR-Code-Encoder-for-Objective-C which seems to have problems (I am getting an error every time I try to run it).

What is an easy straight forward way to make QR codes? I am really desperate here and have been looking online for hours now.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Because that is a good library to use.

Comment: well when i am importing the classes files, i am getting many code errors, and when i am importing the project as they say in the git hub page, when i do a #import "QREncoder.h". I think that when I am importing the project into my project I am misdoing the last step which says "Switch to the Build Settings page, go down to the Search Paths section. (if you have trouble finding it, type "header search" in the search field)
   Add the absolute path to the source code directory to the path list.". Can you explain in more detail what to do here?